# ASP.NET Web API Membership functionality

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership, user-accounts

So I have a rest based service using asp.net web api and also using ninject, and an interface / repository pattern. I currently have no UI as of yet and I am stuck on one thing before I jump into UI.

I am at the point where I would like to implement security - ie: membership, auth, roles and such and I am wondering if anyone can suggest if it would make sense to also implement the security as part of the wep api rest service. So registration, authorization and authentication would use rest to add user.

If this would be ideal is there an example out there which I could model after?

I am guessing that one way I could do this would be this way:

1. Add the sqlmembership to my existing db
2. Create the UI for which will use my web api service
3. Get all the controller logic for user account from UI and put into web api controller
4. Not sure if I would need to use the Interface/Repository pattern which I have in the web api?
5. Move whatever from UI web.config to to webapi web.config related to sqlmembership

Here is a what I am referencing for user accounts - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs

Thanks to whomever responds.

Comment: Seems as if you want to construct a web-api that supports all/most methods of the well known asp.net membership provider, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want. I have created other services via web api. Would it be a similar approach?

Comment: What does anyone think of this as a reference to accomplish what I need to accomplish? http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-your.html

Comment: Well generally I think it's a pretty bad idea to expose a Membership or Roleprovider to a WebAPI like that unless you implement your own access security of these methods.